# Google Maps Style Zoom Control

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, zooming

I am using the Google Maps V3 Javascript API and would like to style the zoom control. Though the Google Documentation has information about moving the Custom Controls it doesn't seem to have any for styling the custom controls. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#ControlModification

What I would like to do is be able to style the existing zoom control.

Is there a way to do style the EXISTING control? I would prefer to do this over creating a new custom control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably need to use JQuery for this as there aren't really any unique classes or IDs for the control. I used a technique similar to here: [Styling standard Zoom control in Google Maps v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5043419/styling-standard-zoom-control-in-google-maps-v3)

Here's my version:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'tilesloaded', function() {
    $('#map_canvas').find('img[src="https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/szc4.png"]').parent('.gmnoprint').css('YOUR_STYLE_HERE', 'YOUR_VALUE_HERE');
});
```

So basically, the above selects the zoom control image, and then steps up one level to get the entire container. You may need to specify a different image than I did, this was for the "Small" version.

Comment: This answer has the issue that it will never age well, google has a tendency to change the images, and in fact they recently did change them to inline svgs so this answer doesn't work anymore

Comment: @Tofandel To be honest I'm amazed it lasted this long as this definitely qualifies as a "hack" in my book. It looks like [Google has added far better tools for handling this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls) since I posted this answer 8 years ago. That said, answers not aging well is probably true of almost any proprietary API ;)

Comment: But they didn't add a way to extend existing ones so unless you rewrite it completely, you can't just modify the image of the zoom control

Answer (score 7):

there's a option for that using google's map API and Custom Control setup, here's a fragment of the code I found:

```
  var map;
var chicago = new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523);

/**
 * The ZoomControl adds +/- button for the map
 *
 */

function ZoomControl(controlDiv, map) {

  // Creating divs & styles for custom zoom control
  controlDiv.style.padding = '5px';

  // Set CSS for the control wrapper
  var controlWrapper = document.createElement('div');
  controlWrapper.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
  controlWrapper.style.borderStyle = 'solid';
  controlWrapper.style.borderColor = 'gray';
  controlWrapper.style.borderWidth = '1px';
  controlWrapper.style.cursor = 'pointer';
  controlWrapper.style.textAlign = 'center';
  controlWrapper.style.width = '32px'; 
  controlWrapper.style.height = '64px';
  controlDiv.appendChild(controlWrapper);

  // Set CSS for the zoomIn
  var zoomInButton = document.createElement('div');
  zoomInButton.style.width = '32px'; 
  zoomInButton.style.height = '32px';
  /* Change this to be the .png image you want to use */
  zoomInButton.style.backgroundImage = 'url("http://placehold.it/32/00ff00")';
  controlWrapper.appendChild(zoomInButton);

  // Set CSS for the zoomOut
  var zoomOutButton = document.createElement('div');
  zoomOutButton.style.width = '32px'; 
  zoomOutButton.style.height = '32px';
  /* Change this to be the .png image you want to use */
  zoomOutButton.style.backgroundImage = 'url("http://placehold.it/32/0000ff")';
  controlWrapper.appendChild(zoomOutButton);

  // Setup the click event listener - zoomIn
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(zoomInButton, 'click', function() {
    map.setZoom(map.getZoom() + 1);
  });

  // Setup the click event listener - zoomOut
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(zoomOutButton, 'click', function() {
    map.setZoom(map.getZoom() - 1);
  });  

}

function initialize() {
  var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map-canvas');

  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 12,
    center: chicago,
    /* Disabling default UI widgets */
    disableDefaultUI: true
  }

  map = new google.maps.Map(mapDiv, mapOptions);

  // Create the DIV to hold the control and call the ZoomControl() constructor
  // passing in this DIV.
  var zoomControlDiv = document.createElement('div');
  var zoomControl = new ZoomControl(zoomControlDiv, map);

  zoomControlDiv.index = 1;
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(zoomControlDiv);
}

initialize();
```

you can see a working example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/maunovaha/jptLfhc8/

Comment: Quoting the OP: "I would prefer to do this over creating a new custom control." which this answer doesn't address.. Sadly, while the buttons are not within an iframe and can be styled with css, they do not have class identifiers and so are not easy to target

Comment: @Tofandel This answer addresses the question. Customizing the default controls with CSS is undocumented and definitely NOT the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

To style the buttons without only using the API, so allowing you to do more things, create the `button` controls via the API - as described above in @Picard answer - and attach to the `div` a `cssClass` property, then style the button as you wish:

```
     var zoomOutButton = document.createElement('div');
         zoomOutButton.className = 'zoom-out-btn';
```

then to style you simply add your rules:

```
     .zoom-out-btn{ /** your rules **/ }
```

same with `zoomInButton`:

```
     var zoomInButton = document.createElement('div');
         zoomInButton.className = 'zoom-in-btn';

     .zoom-in-btn{ /** your rules **/ }
```